# Как узнать, что окно открыто?

Tags: c++, qt, ui

Какой метод отвечает за проверку открытия окна?

P.S.

```
if(window.is...() { //Точками помечено нужный метод
   //code...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы про метод `isVisible()`

```
if(window->isVisible())
```

[Документация](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#properties)